# Is it ok for a method to call itself again after catching an exception?

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-mail

I have a background job running and every morning at 7:00 am calls a method in order to send an email to certain address, I'm using java mail for that. 
The reason I'm asking this is because **sometimes** it sends a `MessagingException`(always this exception when it happens). This is the error:

```
nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated
```

As I said, it happens only from time to time; but it is a little annoying since I have to make sure to send the mail manually in case it fails. I haven't found the reason for this to happen, I tried looking this up and some answers suggest that is a problem with the server; unfortunally I don't have control over it. When I execute the routine manually, sometimes it takes up to 5 or 7 tries until the mail is sent.

So what i'm trying to do is call the same method in the catch section, also I'd put a counter to control the number of attempts in case the exception is catched more than let's say 5 times.

Would you suggest this approach?  I appreciate your help and answers.

Here is the code for the method I'm trying to re-call everytime the MessagingException is thrown:

```
  public void sendMail(String msj, String dest, String asunto, File attachmentSource, int count) {
        String to = dest;
        String from = "some.user@vw.com.mx";
        String host = "someserver.xx.xx.xx";
        boolean debug = true;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        if (debug) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "");
        }
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        session.setDebug(debug);
        try {
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
            msg.setSubject("Reporte");
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());
            msg.setText(msj);
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(attachmentSource)));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(attachmentSource.getName());
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            msg.setContent(multipart);

            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SendMSG.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ("ERROR EN ENVÍO!!!! " + mex.getMessage()));
            //THIS IS a TEST TO TRY UNTIL THE MSG IS SENT
            count++;
            if (count <= 5) {
                Logger.getLogger(SendMSG.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, ("Intento No:  " + count + " de 5" + mex.getMessage()));
                sendMail(msj, dest, asunto, attachmentSource, count);                
            } else {
                Logger.getLogger(SendMSG.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, ("No. de Intentos excedido " + count + " SALIR DE MÉTODO" + mex.getMessage()));
            }
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use a loop?

Comment: Yes but what will you achieve ? an infinite stack all with errors... ?

Comment: There is nothing in the language to prevent this; but it does sound like using exception handling for flow control; remember an exception should be an exceptional circumstance

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is fine, but quite messy. I'd separate retries and sending.

```
public boolean sendMail(String msj, String dest, String asunto, File attachmentSource, int retries) {
    for (int i = 0; i< retries; i++){
        if (sendMail(msj, dest, asunto, attachmentSource)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean sendMail(String msj, String dest, String asunto, File attachmentSource) {
    try {
        ...
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It does basically the same thing as your code, but improves readability.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a way of separating two things: executing main logic of your method and a behaviour in case of failure. If you could write an interface, kind of `ExceptionHandler` where you declare a method `handleFault` (for example). Then, in your main class you could inject some specific implementation of `ExceptionHandler` where you decide what to do in case of failure.

This would make testing easier because you can substitute your "live" or "production" or whatever we call it behaviour from a simple, testing one, where you just want to check if the faulty case was handled.

I think it's really worth taking a look on a **ciruit breaker pattern** described here by Martin Fowler: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html

You can have a separate strategies for handling errors, retry templates (how many retries, time between them, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to assume that the error is dependent on time. Since it sometimes happens and sometimes doesn't. With that in mind, I suggest putting wait() inside the loop after `count++`

like this:

```
synchronized (this) 
        {
        this.wait(count*1000);//delay after each error
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's some helpful suggestions in the other answers, but I think a core part of your problem is that you're **never** authenticating to the server.  Unless you're using a local server that doesn't require authentication, I don't know how this ever works.

As explained in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#smtpauth), replace your Transport.send call with

```
Transport.send(msg, username, password);
```

Where username and password are the credentials to login to your mail server.